# Vim - How to enter the command-line window without stopping a macro recording?

Tags: vim, macros

A macro recording is stopped using the character "q". Also, the command-line window is popularly known to be accessed using "q:". Thus, when one records a macro and wants to enter the command-line window, one will often stop one's macro mistakenly. How do you open it differently?

Comment: Hey, I have this issue as well. Did you find a solution for it. The one listed below does not seem to be working

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple! Bram explains [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-window) that if you want to access the command-line, you must use `q:`, or press `<c-f>` while in command-line mode. Meaning, you just have to press `:<c-f>`. Some specific conditions must be met for that to be possible though, make sure to read provided link.